# Install pg_strom extension using Window 7

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am not a native English speaker so please ignore my grammar mistakes.

I want to add or install  **pg_strom** extension having postgresql (11.5) in my local machine using windows 7, I search a alot and got most of the solution are on Linux based.

Is there any way to add or install  **pg_strom** extension having postgresql (11.5) in my local machine using windows 7 in it.

And please also guide me, "I want to use pg_storm only to reduce my path finding queries time with the help of GPU", is it right way or not.

If not please suggest me right way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask this on https://github.com/heterodb/pg-strom/issues.

Note that in general PostgreSQL extensions coded in C are available on Linux but not always on Windows: but even with Windows 7 you should be able to create a Linux virtual machine with VirtualBox to have PostgreSQL on Linux and all extensions available.